# Tizen Native App Webview privileges

Tags: webview, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

On the online guide, the following privileges are listed as necessary to place Webview in my application, however, app crashes due to privilege error when I run it outside the emulator. Same thing happened to me before with one of my applications and I fixed the problem by adding the relevant permissions to the manifest. In this case I am lost since privileges that are listed online does not seem necessary for the Webview. Can you help me if you used Webview in your native applications before?

```
<privileges>
   <!--To launch another application conditionally-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch</privilege>
   <!--To create, update, and delete content-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/content.write</privilege>
   <!--To use the Internet connection-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/internet</privilege>
   <!--To provide user notifications, such as messages and badges-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/notification</privilege>
   <!--To use the user location data-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/location</privilege>
   <!--To manage the device cameras to preview and capture pictures-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/camera</privilege>
   <!--To access, read, and write to the external storage-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/externalstorage</privilege>
   <!--To access the display-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/display</privilege>
   <!--To create a network connection-->
   <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/network.get</privilege>
</privileges>
```

Comment: You may follow this tutorial. May help you https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/webview-native-application

Comment: **How about contacting the [Tizen App School](http://tizenschool.org/)?**
It is a site **created by Tizen developers** for other developers.
If you leave a comment for this issue, they may prepare the lecture or the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Privilige `http://tizen.org/privilege/network.get` is not available in web applications. As the [documentation](https://www.tizen.org/ko/privilege?langredirect=1#privilege/network.get) says. It's only for native apps.

[Here](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/web-application/understanding-tizen-programming/security-and-api-privileges?langredirect=1#mobile_api) you have all WEB privileges for Tizen OS. Both mobile and wearable.

[Here](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/native-application/understanding-tizen-programming/security-and-api-privileges?langredirect=1#mobile_native) you have all NATIVE priviliges for TizenOS.